# How Iscontain can return string

Tags: sql, zoho

I need help with Z0h0 Analytics Formula Column

I have table like

```
Consume
Energy Coal
Energy Non Coal
Physical
Physical
Magic
```

I want to make like this

```
Consume             Group
Energy Coal         EG
Energy  Non coal    EG 
Physical            PY
Magic               MG
```

right now i am using `iscontain` but failed

`iscontain("Consume",'Energy')='EG'`
`iscontain("Consume",'Physical')='PY'`
`iscontain("Consume",'Magic')='MG'`

It doesn't work if i using this. i think `iscontain` only return `boleean`.
Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can use like operator

```
select Consume, 
       case when Consume like '%Energy%' then 'EG'
       when Consume like '%Physical%' then 'PY'
       when Consume like '%Magic%' then 'MG' end as group
from tablename
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I just know i can use when case in zoho.